# AWK loop to parse file

Tags: loops, awk

I have trouble understandig an awk command which I want to change slightly (but can't because I don't understand the code enough).
The result of this awk command is to put together text files having 6 columns. In the output file, the first column is a mix of all first column of the input file. The other columns of the output file are the other column of the input file with added blank if needed, to still match with the first column values.

First, I would like to only parse some specific columns from these files and not all 6. I couldn't figure out where to specify it in the awk loop.

Secondly, the header of the columns are not the first row of the output file anymore. It would be nice to have it as header in the output file as well.

Thirdly, I need to know from which file the data comes from. I know that the command take the files in the order they appear when doing ls -lh *mosdepth.summary.txt so I can deduce that the first 6 columns are from file 1, the 6 next from file 2, ect. However, I would like to automatically have this information in the output file to reduce the potential human errors I can do by infering the origin of the data.

Here is the awk command

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" 'F!=FILENAME { FNUM++; F=FILENAME }

{       COL[$1]++;        C=$1; $1="";        A[C, FNUM]=$0 }

END {
        for(X in COL)
        {
                printf("%s", X);
                for(N=1; N<=FNUM; N++) printf("%s", A[X, N]);
                printf("\n");
        }
}' *mosdepth.summary.txt > Se_combined.coverage.txt
```

the input file look like this

```
cat file1
chrom   length  bases   mean    min     max
contig_1_pilon  223468  603256  2.70    0       59
contig_2_pilon  197061  1423255 7.22    0       102
contig_6_pilon  162902  1372153 8.42    0       80
contig_19_pilon 286502  1781926 6.22    0       243
contig_29_pilon 263348  1251842 4.75    0       305
contig_32_pilon 291449  1819758 6.24    0       85
contig_34_pilon 51310   197150  3.84    0       29
contig_37_pilon 548146  4424483 8.07    0       399
contig_41_pilon 7529    163710  21.74   0       59
```

```
cat file2
chrom   length  bases   mean    min     max
contig_2_pilon  197061  2098426 10.65   0       198
contig_19_pilon 286502  1892283 6.60    0       233
contig_32_pilon 291449  2051790 7.04    0       172
contig_37_pilon 548146  6684861 12.20   0       436
contig_42_pilon 14017   306188  21.84   0       162
contig_79_pilon 17365   883750  50.89   0       1708
contig_106_pilon        513441  6917630 13.47   0       447
contig_124_pilon        187518  374354  2.00    0       371
contig_149_pilon        1004879 13603882        13.54   0       801
```

the wrong output looks like this

```
contig_149_pilon        1004879 13603882        13.54   0       801
contig_79_pilon 17365   883750  50.89   0       1708
contig_1_pilon  223468  603256  2.70    0       59
contig_106_pilon        513441  6917630 13.47   0       447
contig_2_pilon  197061  1423255 7.22    0       102     197061  2098426 10.65   0       198
chrom   length  bases   mean    min     max     length  bases   mean    min     max
contig_37_pilon 548146  4424483 8.07    0       399     548146  6684861 12.20   0       436
contig_41_pilon 7529    163710  21.74   0       59
contig_6_pilon  162902  1372153 8.42    0       80
contig_42_pilon 14017   306188  21.84   0       162
contig_29_pilon 263348  1251842 4.75    0       305
contig_19_pilon 286502  1781926 6.22    0       243     286502  1892283 6.60    0       233
contig_124_pilon        187518  374354  2.00    0       371
contig_34_pilon 51310   197150  3.84    0       29
contig_32_pilon 291449  1819758 6.24    0       85      291449  2051790 7.04    0       172
```

EDIT:
Thanks to several input from several users I manage to answer my points 1 and 3 like this

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" 'F!=FILENAME { FNUM++; F=FILENAME }

{   B[FNUM]=F;  COL[$1];        C=$1; $1="";       A[C, FNUM]=$4}

END {
        printf("%s\t", "contig")
        for (N=1; N<=FNUM; N++) 
        {   printf("%.5s\t", B[N])}
        printf("\n")
        for(X in COL)
        {
                printf("%s\t", X);
                for(N=1; N<=FNUM; N++) 
                {   printf("%s\t", A[X, N]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }   
}' file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

with output

```
contig  file1   file2
contig_149_pilon                13.54
contig_79_pilon         50.89
contig_1_pilon  2.70
contig_106_pilon                13.47
contig_2_pilon  7.22    10.65
chrom   mean    mean
contig_37_pilon 8.07    12.20
contig_41_pilon 21.74
contig_6_pilon  8.42
contig_42_pilon         21.84
contig_29_pilon 4.75
contig_19_pilon 6.22    6.60
contig_124_pilon                2.00
contig_34_pilon 3.84
contig_32_pilon 6.24    7.04
```

Comment: please update the question to include sample input data (in textual form we can cut-n-paste into our environment; do not post as an image), the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output; when providing sample inputs please provide 5-10 lines from 2-3 different files, and the (wrong, expected) outputs should then correspond with these sample inputs

Comment: For 1, use `$2, $3, $4` instead of `$0` to process just those 3 columns. For 3, the file number is in `N`, so you can print that in the output.

Comment: You could solve part2 of your question by adding: `NR==1{ h=$0; }` to your question and a `print h` to the END part.  `NR==1` will run on the first line of input, saving your header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk processes files in records, where the records are separated by the record separator `RS`. Each record is split in fields where the field separator is defined by the variable `FS` that the `-F` flag can define.

In the case of the program presented in the OP, the record separator is the default value which is the <newline>-character and the field separator is set to be the <tab>-character.

Awk programs are generally written as a sequence of pattern-action pairs of the form `pattern { action }`. These pairs are executed sequentially and state to perform `action` when `pattern` returns a non-zero or non-empty string value.

In the current program there are three such action-patter pairs:

1. **`F!=FILENAME { FNUM++; F=FILENAME }`**: This states that if the value of `F` is different from the current `FILENAME` which is processed, then increase the value of `FNUM` with one and update the value of `F` with the current `FILENAME`.

   In the end, this is the same as just checking if we are processing a new file or not. The equivalent version of this would be:

   ```
   (FNR==1) { FNUM++ }
   ```

   which reads: *If we are processing the first record of the current file (`FNR`), then increase the file count `FNUM`*.
2. **`{ COL[$1]++; C=$1; $1=""; A[C, FNUM]=$0 }`**: As there is no pattern, it implies true by default. So here, for each record/line increment the number of times you saw the value in the first column and store it in an associative array `COL` (key-value pairs). Memorize the first field in `C` and store in an array `A` the value of the current record, but remove the first field. So if the record of the second file reads "foo A B C D", and `foo` already been seen 3 times, then, `COL["foo"]` will be equal to 4 and `A["foo",2]` will read " A B C D".
3. **`END{ ... }`** This is a special pattern-action pair. Here `END` indicates that this `action` should only be executed at the end, when all files have been processed. What the end statement does, is straightforward, it just prints all records of each file. Including empty records.

In the end, this entire script can be simplified to the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\t" }
     { file_list[FILENAME]
       key_list[$1]
       record_list[FILENAME,$1]=$0 }
     END { for (key in key_list)
             for (fname in file_list) 
                print ( record_list[fname,key] ? record_list[fname,key] : key )
     }' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Comment: "still working on it." ???  Did you know you can delete your own comment when the comment is no longer valid ? (or are you really "still working on it.")

Comment: @kvantour Thanks a lot for the explaination, it helps a lot for my general understanding. As I didn't state my question very well, your code is not exactly what I was looking for but I manage to find a decent answer now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your '*mosdepth.summary.txt' files look like the following:

```
$ ls *mos*txt
1mosdepth.summary.txt 2mosdepth.summary.txt 3mosdepth.summary.txt
```

And contents are:

```
$ cat 1mosdepth.summary.txt
chrom   length  bases   mean    min max
contig_1_pilon  223468  1181176 5.29    0   860
contig_2_pilon  197061  2556215 12.97   0   217
contig_6_pilon  162902  2132156 13.09   0   80


$ cat 2mosdepth.summary.txt
chrom   length  bases   mean    min max
contig_19_pilon 286502  2067244 7.22    0   345
contig_29_pilon 263348  2222566 8.44    0   765
contig_32_pilon 291449  2671881 9.17  0 128
contig_34_pilon 51310   525393  10.24   0   47

$ cat 3mosdepth.summary.txt
chrom   length  bases   mean    min max
contig_37_pilon 548146  6652322 12.14   0   558
contig_41_pilon 7529    144989  19.26   0   71
```

The following `awk` command might be appropriate:

```
$ awk -v target_cols="1 2 3 4 5 6" 'BEGIN{split(target_cols, cols," ")} \
 NR==1{printf "%s ", "file#"; for (i=1;i<=length(cols);i++) {printf "%s ", $cols[i]} print ""} \
FNR==1{fnbr++} \
FNR>=2{printf "%s ", fnbr; for (i=1;i<=length(cols);i++) {printf "%s ", $cols[i]} print ""}' *mos*txt | column -t
```

Output:

```
file#  chrom            length  bases    mean   min  max
1      contig_1_pilon   223468  1181176  5.29   0    860
1      contig_2_pilon   197061  2556215  12.97  0    217
1      contig_6_pilon   162902  2132156  13.09  0    80
2      contig_19_pilon  286502  2067244  7.22   0    345
2      contig_29_pilon  263348  2222566  8.44   0    765
2      contig_32_pilon  291449  2671881  9.17   0    128
2      contig_34_pilon  51310   525393   10.24  0    47
3      contig_37_pilon  548146  6652322  12.14  0    558
3      contig_41_pilon  7529    144989   19.26  0    71
```

Alternatively, the following will output the filename rather than file#:

```
$ awk -v target_cols="1 2 3 4 5 6" 'BEGIN{split(target_cols, cols," ")} \
 NR==1{printf "%s ", "fname"; for (i=1;i<=length(cols);i++) {printf "%s ", $cols[i]} print ""} \
FNR==1{fnbr=FILENAME} \
FNR>=2{printf "%s ", fnbr; fnbr="-"; for (i=1;i<=length(cols);i++) {printf "%s ", $cols[i]} print ""}' *mos*txt | column -t
```

Output:

```
fname                  chrom            length  bases    mean   min  max
1mosdepth.summary.txt  contig_1_pilon   223468  1181176  5.29   0    860
-                      contig_2_pilon   197061  2556215  12.97  0    217
-                      contig_6_pilon   162902  2132156  13.09  0    80
2mosdepth.summary.txt  contig_19_pilon  286502  2067244  7.22   0    345
-                      contig_29_pilon  263348  2222566  8.44   0    765
-                      contig_32_pilon  291449  2671881  9.17   0    128
-                      contig_34_pilon  51310   525393   10.24  0    47
3mosdepth.summary.txt  contig_37_pilon  548146  6652322  12.14  0    558
-                      contig_41_pilon  7529    144989   19.26  0    71
```

With either command, the `target_cols="1 2 3 4 5 6"` specifies the targeted columns to extract.

`target_cols="1 2 3"` for example, will produce:

```
fname                  chrom            length  bases
1mosdepth.summary.txt  contig_1_pilon   223468  1181176
-                      contig_2_pilon   197061  2556215
-                      contig_6_pilon   162902  2132156
2mosdepth.summary.txt  contig_19_pilon  286502  2067244
-                      contig_29_pilon  263348  2222566
-                      contig_32_pilon  291449  2671881
-                      contig_34_pilon  51310   525393
3mosdepth.summary.txt  contig_37_pilon  548146  6652322
-                      contig_41_pilon  7529    144989
```

`target_cols="4 5 6"` will produce:

```
fname                  mean   min  max
1mosdepth.summary.txt  5.29   0    860
-                      12.97  0    217
-                      13.09  0    80
2mosdepth.summary.txt  7.22   0    345
-                      8.44   0    765
-                      9.17   0    128
-                      10.24  0    47
3mosdepth.summary.txt  12.14  0    558
-                      19.26  0    71
```